# TimThumb like dynamic image resizing bundle for Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Does anyone know how to achieve famous [TimThumb](https://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/) like dynamic image resizing in Laravel 5. Basically I want to resize and show the image from external URL while loading the page and save it in the cache for the next page load. Exactly the same what TimThumb does. I am a newbie in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Intervention it's more efficient then TimThumb as we know
and also it for laravel easy to use to resize and all
http://image.intervention.io/

hope this will help you